# How to format numbers based on row condition in Pandas to_html

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with columns country measure and values :

```
Country| Measures| Value|
US    |Sales    |10000.000
US    |Share %  |0.10265
US    |Price    |15.82564
UK    |Sales    |10500.000
UK    |Share %  |0.30265
UK    |Price    |13.72564
```

I load dataframe from database which has floating point number upto 6 digits,
I want below fomat in html

```
Country| Measures |Values
US    |Sales    |10000
US    |Share %  |10.2%
US    |Price    |15.83
UK    |Sales    |10500
UK    |Share %  |30.27%
UK    |Price    |13.72
```

Using 'float_format'  or  'formatters '  parameter of df.to_html function I can convert all number into desired format or column specific format respectively

below code I used in column specific formatting 
where I have Share and price in columns not in rows

```
df.to_html(index=False, formatters={ 'Share %': '{:,.1%}'.format,
                                                      'Price': '{:,.1f}'.format})
```

But here my requirement is to format on the basis of rows

I want

1. sales number in Integer
2. Share number in percentage with 2 decimal
3. Price number with 2 decimal

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you opposed to using pandas number formatting tools *prior* to writing to html? Pandas has plenty of rounding/formatting tools that you can apply before you write the dataframe to html.

Comment: to_html will accept format from dataframe ? let me have a try  Can you suggest a code for above requirement in case of dataframe formatting

Comment: I'm saying that the most logical solution seems to be doing all the formatting before you write, thus avoiding using the `formatters` keyword in `to_html`. I'm describing what piRSquared already posted below so just refer to his example.

Comment: thanks Brian for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use string formatting

```
fmap = dict(
    Sales='{:0.0f}'.format,
    Price='{:0.2f}'.format,
    Share='{:0.2%}'.format
)

df.assign(Value=[fmap[m](v) for m, v in zip(df.Measures, df.Value)])

  Country Measures   Value
0      US    Sales   10000
1      US    Share  10.27%
2      US    Price   15.83
3      UK    Sales   10500
4      UK    Share  30.26%
5      UK    Price   13.73
```

---

Alternate dictionary specification

```
fmap = {
    'Sales': '{:0.0f}'.format,
    'Price': '{:0.2f}'.format,
    'Share': '{:0.2%}'.format
}
```

Comment: thanks piRSquared, how can be dictionary formed as my row label is 'Value share %' instead of 'share'  as above was sample data I guess keys with space will not be accepted ?

Comment: I posted an alternative to defining the dictionary.

Comment: Great, It's working, One last thing if I have 5 numeric columns then how I can modify apply function on multiple column I tried storing column name in list and used above code but it's not working `col_lst = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']    for col in col_lst :  jv_report[col] = jv_report.assign(col=[fmap[m](v) for m, v in zip(jv_report.metric, jv_report[col])])`